# How do I continually get info from a server?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, retrofit

I have an Android client that needs to request information from my server (using  retrofit). The information on my server is updated randomly and can be updated at any moment and I am limited by the fact that I am **not allowed to use cloud technologies**, everything is to be self hosted. Does this prevent me from using GCM and Firebase? If so, are there more elegant solutions other than calling GET every second in the background?

Comment: there should be no problem, you can send FCM messages directly from your server when the information is updated

Comment: Can you link me to some resources in order to do that? All resources I see online say things like `cloud to device` and [this graphic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/images/messaging-overview.png) says that it all connects via cloud.